# Check link refers to external site

Tags: jquery

Apologies in advanced if you have seen a similar question. I've tried looking up what I need to help convert this code, but to little effect and it's late.

I'm trying to figure out how to change:

```
 if (link.substr(0, 4) == 'http://localhost','https://localhost')
    // If the link starts with http, assume external link.
    // In that case, block normal behaviour, insert custom content and navigate after 5 seconds.
    event.preventDefault();
```

to basically its reverse making any links that don't start with localhost to receive the rest of the script. While links that do ignore the script all together. I have tried to use if, else, and return statements but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks again for any help!

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Capture all link clicks.
$('a').on('click', function(event) {

  // Get the element and its href attribute.
  var $element = $(event.target);
  var link = $element.attr('href');

  if (link.substr(0, 4) == 'http://localhost','https://localhost')
    // If the link starts with http, assume external link.
    // In that case, block normal behaviour, insert custom content and navigate after 5 seconds.
    event.preventDefault();

    $element.html("Leaving this website in 5...");

    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("This is when the redirect would take place, if not in Staack Snippets");
      document.location.href = link;
    }, 5000);
  }
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the answer with this code. It essentially allows all links that include the domain name ('localhost') in my case to ignore the code via ('.not') event. The next part of the script loads an overlay before starting a delay timer on the link.

```
   $('a[href^="http://"],a[href^="https://"]')
        .not('[href*="localhost"]')
        .click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var goTo = this.getAttribute("href");

        $(function() {

        var loading = function() {
            var over = '<div id="overlay">' +
                '<img id="loading" src="/">' +
                '</div>';
            $(over).appendTo('body');
        };
        loading()
        });
        setTimeout(function(){

             window.location = goTo;
        },5000);       
    });
```